# DRF - upload CSV file then iterate over each row

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I don't need to save the file to the db, just upload the file so I can go over each row and perform some operations based on the data in those rows. Using regular Django views I can iterate over each row in a CSV file like this:

```
class FileUploadForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()

class ProductUpload(FormView):
    template_name = 'file_upload.html'
    form_class = FileUploadForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        file = form.cleaned_data['file']
        decoded_file = file.read().decode()
        io_string = io.StringIO(file)
        reader = csv.reader(io_string)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
        messages.success(self.request, 'File uploaded successfully.')
        return redirect(self.request.path)
```

But I can't figure it out using Django Rest Framework. I'm using `parsers.FileUploadParser` but not sure if this is correct - the form will be submitted through browser on the front end.

```
class ProductUploadAPIView(views.APIView):
    parser_classes = (parsers.FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file = request.data['file']
        decoded_file = file.read().decode()
        # upload_products_csv.delay(decoded_file, request.user.pk)
        io_string = io.StringIO(decoded_file)
        reader = csv.reader(io_string)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Here's my cURL request and the console output

`curl -v -X POST -u user:pass http://localhost:8000/api/file_upload/ -F "file=./file.csv" -H "Content-Type: text/csv" -H "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv"`

```
['--------------------------8e8e5ed08fe4ca99']
['Content-Disposition: attachment; name="file"']
[]
['./file.csv']
['--------------------------8e8e5ed08fe4ca99--']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had to use a serializer with `serializers.FileField` instead of a parser.

```
class FileUploadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    file = serializers.FileField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('file',)

class FileUploadAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = FileUploadSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        file = serializer.validated_data['file']
        decoded_file = file.read().decode()
        # upload_products_csv.delay(decoded_file, request.user.pk)
        io_string = io.StringIO(decoded_file)
        reader = csv.reader(io_string)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```